# .new isn't a function when deploying contract (web3)

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to deploy contracts using Ganache but I'm getting the following error.

I have my ABI and contract address defined, all other functions with respect to interacting with the contract work, however I cannot create a new one. Any ideas? Thanks.

The code is below...

```
newContract: function(error, result) {
  createContract.new(quantity,name,decimals,symbol,{from:account,gas:21000}).then(function(instance) {

  if (!instance.address) {
    console.log("Contract at: " + instance.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined");

  } else {
    console.log("Contract mined. Here it is: " + instance.address);
    console.log(contract);
  }

  console.log(instance.address);    
});
```

This is the error -

> TypeError: createContract.new is not a function

Update:
It is initialized via

```
var createContract = web3.eth.contract(createContractabi);
```

I'm wondering if the error is being generated as my currentprovider is giving an error...

Both `createContract.setProvider(this.web3.currentProvider);` and `createContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);` were tried.

However, both fail, with the errors

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined

and

> TypeError: createContract.setProvider is not a function

respectively.

Comment: You're missing some code. How is `createContract` initialized? You should have something like `const createContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was always initialized...but unfortunately the error is still occurring.

Comment: .new is for 0.17 and above. If you are using 1.0.0, use this: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html